# Android - Accessing View in ListView after call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged and ListView.setSelection

Tags: android, listview, view, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have:

`ArrayList<SubwordInfo> subwordInfoList` - my data - list of `SubwordInfo` objects.

`ListView lvSubwords` - ListView for showing my data

`SubwordListAdapter subwordListAdapter` - my own adapter between `subwordInfoList` and `lvSubwords` (based on BaseAdapter).

At some point I want make a simple thing:

1. Update data item in `subwordInfoList`.
2. Update appearence of corresponding child view in `lvSubwords`.
3. Positionize `lvSubwords` on this child view.
4. Run animation on this child view.

Steps 1 - 3 working fine. But step 4 is a problem, because I cant access child view in a right way. I'm getting wrong child view or null.

There's code:

```
SubwordInfo si;
...
si=subwordInfoList.get(subwordNo);

<updating si>

subwordListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  //Notify for update - successfull
lvSubwords.setSelection(subwordNo);         //Positionize - successfull
```

And after this I trying to access child view, corresponding to `si`.

I tried to do this:

```
View view = lvSubwords.getChildAt(subwordNo-lvSubwords.getFirstVisiblePosition());
if (view!=null)
    view.startAnimation(animHighlight);
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (view==NULL). Sometimes, view is wrong view.

Also I tried using view tags:

```
View view = lvSubwords.findViewWithTag(si);
if (view!=null)
    view.startAnimation(animHighlight);
```

Tags are assigned before in getView of adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
{
    View view = arg1;
    if (view == null) 
      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.subword_element, arg2, false);

    SubwordInfo si = getSubwordInfo(arg0);

    ...

    view.setTag(si);//Assigning tags

    return view;        
}
```

It works only if `lvSubwords.getFirstVisiblePosition()` was 0 BEFORE calling `subwordListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `lvSubwords.setSelection`. Otherwise, view is null.

Also, I found out that `lvSubwords.getFirstVisiblePosition()` returns same value before and after call `lvSubwords.setSelection`.

So, it seems to me, that after calling `subwordListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `lvSubwords.setSelection` child views of ListView and ListView itself doesn't immediately updating. And they will update sometime later. How can I catch this moment and get my desirable child view for animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a bit since I've done this, but I believe you have it a little backwards. SetSelection should align what ever adapter position given to the top of the `ListView`.  That means, you should be fine with just always grabbing the child at index 0.

Also, yes `setSelection` does not happen immediately. It'll fire things off and not finish till some time later. I ran into a similar problem quite a bit ago and the only solution I could come up with was to `postDelay` a runnable with the actions you want done.

```
lvSubwords.setSelection(subwordNo);
lvSubwords.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Get View and start animation
    }
}, 66);
```

You may need to play around with how long you have to wait for.

Comment: Thank you, it's working. And it is working with 66ms also :) But it still seems to me a bit inaccurately. Because I'm "guessing" moment - when I can access the view. Is it really no way to find out this moment more more precisely? If it wasn't touch mode, then it would be onSetSelection event, but there is no selection in touch mode and this event isn't triggering. Android seems to me a bit clunky...

Comment: I have played with delay time and found out, that it is working even with 0 delay. So, I think - no matter how long delay is, this message will be proceessed AFTER pending messages of the view, including messages for updating state of the view, so at any delay, state of ListView will be surely updated and I can access right view. If I understand it right...